# What text editor supports MySQL autocompletion?

Tags: mysql, autocomplete, command, prompt

Does anybody know what text editor supports a feature which is auto completion for codes in mysql prompt? I really have trouble in finding the answer. I cant find what text editor it is. Im dealing with my research project now. 
Thanks for replies.

Answer (score 0):

Probably vim with the appropriate DB plugin…

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=356